# How to add modified dictionary into a list without changing the one that is already in that list in python?

Tags: python

I meet a problem when trying to continuously add modified dictionaries into the same list. I simplified what I want to do below:

```
a = {"1":"1"}
b = [a]

for i in range (2,5):
 a["1"] = i
 b.append(a)

print(b)
```

This will give me

```
[{'1': 4}, {'1': 4}, {'1': 4}, {'1': 4}]
```

But I want b as

```
[{'1': 1}, {'1': 2}, {'1': 3}, {'1': 4}]
```

How should I do this?

Comment: you need to copy the dict, e.g. `a = dict(a)` in the loop

Comment: alternatively `{"1": i for i in range(1,5)}`

Answer (score 0):

Do not reuse the "a" dict inside the loop
and create a new small dict each time it is needed
You can do like this:

```
a = {"1":"1"}
b = [a]

for i in range (2,5):
    b.append({"1":i})

print(b)
```

the result is :

```
[{'1': '1'}, {'1': 2}, {'1': 3}, {'1': 4}]
```